# Python request response - if elif condition not working

Tags: python

Hi there I am having trouble with my code on if else json response and I'm pretty sure I am doing the correct way but the code doesn't continue on the else statement.

```
import requests
import psycopg2
        conn = psycopg2.connect(dbname='databasename',user='postgres',password='12345',host='x.x.x.x', port='xxxx') # works correctly
        print('success db')
        cur = conn.cursor()

        cur.execute("SELECT mobile_number FROM users WHERE status='ACTIVE'") # this is my query 
        conn.commit();
        row_count = cur.rowcount
        print('This is the number of rows: ', row_count)
        result = [mobileNum[0] for mobileNum in cur.fetchall()]

        for mobileNum in result:
            print('Current Number: ', mobileNum)
            pushnotif = push_notif(mobileNum) # This is a function for http request
            
            if pushnotif['success'] == 1 and pushnotif['failure'] == 0 : # This line of code is working and continue the for loop
                print('Success!!!')
            elif pushnotif['success'] == 0 and pushnotif['failure'] == 1: # This line of code is working but only when I'm printing a sentence like faileedddd!
                print(pushnotif['results']['error']) # This doesn't print the result error on http response and exits the for loop
            elif pushnotif['message'] == "Invalid number": # This line doesn't work and end the for loops
                print(pushnotif['message'])
            else: # The code doesn't go here whenever the response is not 200 OK or push_notif['message'] or push_notif['results''error']
                print('error')
```

Below is a sample of response:

```
{
    "multicast_id": xxx,
    "success": 1,
    "failure": 0,
    "canonical_ids": 0,
    "results": [
        {
            "message_id": "xxx"
        }
    ]
}
```

or

```
{
    "multicast_id": xxxx,
    "success": 0,
    "failure": 1,
    "canonical_ids": 0,
    "results": [
        {
            "error": "invalid"
        }
    ]
}
```

or

```
{
    "message": "Invalid number"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
pushnotif = push_notif(mobileNum)
pushlen = len(pushnotif)

if pushlen == 5:
     print("This will print if API response is equal to 5", pushnotif)
elif pushlen == 1:
     print("This will print if API response is equal to 1", pushnotif)
else:
     print("This will print unexpected response", pushnotif)
```

This is the logic thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the function `push_notif` returns, but if it returns a regular `dict` this may be a problem as you are assuming that the keys `(success, failure and result)` are present in the dict, which is not the case for the last response example you provided. so typically an exception will raise and stop your program, or at least if caught, ends the for loop and exit the function.

Comment: What should I then? TIA

Answer (score 0):

Let's say, for example, you got initially the below responses.

```
{
    "message": "Invalid number"
}
```

Here your dictionary has only one key named `message`.So, when you are checking your response with keys like `success`, `failure`, your program will stop executing as these keys are not present in your current response and your else statement will never be executed.

Comment: I see thank you for this information. However, Do you know a way wherein I can do an if else statement where the response such as ```message``` will considered?

Comment: @Mawty I think you can check the number of key-value you get from the responses. In your first and second responses mentioned in your question, you will get 5 responses and for the last one, you have only 1 value. This can be a way to differentiate your responses.

Comment: @Mawty if you feel my answer is right, I would like you to upvote or mark it as accepted. This will help another user to get the correct answer easily. Thanks

Comment: I think I did what you just meant regarding the if else statement but how should I write it into code? Should I use len since you told me to check the number of key-value? Again,thank you in advance. I would mark it as accepted the soonest I find a way to write it into code.

Comment: @Mawty, First of all, find the length of your response `pushnotif`  using `len`. Then depending on the value of the response, you have to rewrite the `if-else`cases. Hope this clarifies a bit more.

Comment: @Mawty seems like the idea of finding `len` has worked for you.

Comment: @Mawty you are most welcome. Upvote will encourage me further